# find a largest sum contiguous sub array from a given array consisting of integers

Tags: c, arrays, loops, traversal, sub-array

I am writing a code to find the maximum sum contiguous sub array in C. The logic seems fine according to me, but still the output is not correct. Please look into the code.in the three loops the second loop runs from the first value keeing the value from the first loop fixed and the third loop is to get the sum of the sub array.Please look into the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int A[10],i,j;
void lsa(int A[],int n)
{
    int m,l,z,max=0,sum;
    for(m=0;m<n;m++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(l=0;l<n;l++)
        {
            for(z=m;z<=l;z++)
            {
                if(m==l)                 //maximum sum from a contiguous sub array
                {
                }
               else
                {
                    sum=A[z]+A[l];
                    if(sum>max)
                    {
                        max=sum;
                        i=m;
                        j=l;
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
void main()
{
    int n,p;
    printf("enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter array elements\n");        //creation of array
    for(p=0;p<n;p++)
        scanf("%d",&A[p]);
        lsa(A,n);
        printf("sub array is\n");
        for(p=i;p<j;p++)
        {
             printf("%d ",A[p]);
        }
}
```

Comment: `Please look into the code`..... With this indentation: NO.

Comment: This code does not do what you expect, fine but you should give an example of input and the expected and obtained output. And you should describe the algorithm you tried to implement intead of just giving uncommented code. BTW, you should make sure `n < 10`...

Comment: FYI, an acceptable solution is supposed to be linear time.

Comment: The logic is wrong: sum if badly calculated, not initialized in the correct place... Implementation is worse: `for(p=0;p<n;p++)
scanf("%d",&A[i]);` only writes first element of array (i instead of p in loop). Show at least a little work before asking here.

Comment: `if(m==l)` should be tested above of `for(z=m...` not inside. If `for(z=m...` calculates the sum, `sum=0;` should be above this loop;
If your array doesn't contain negative values, the result should always be `i==0 and j==n`

Comment: could figure it out.Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

**There are many problems in your code.**

In the first `for` loop of `main` function, you have :

```
for(p=0;p<n;p++)
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
```

- `i` is global variable and uninitialized, so you aren't even scanning the elements into your element properly
- You've messed up your `lsa` function which doesn't produce correct results even when  the above for loop is fixed
- and one of the limitations of your code is that it only works for arrays of size `10` or less

---

I understand the way you want to find largest contiguous array.. as you said :

> - the second loop runs from the first value keeping the value from the first loop fixed
> - and the third loop is to get the sum of the sub array

I'd say instead of making a third loop and making code look messy, it's better breaking it down into another function which calculates the sum of sub-array

---

**Solution :**

Here I've provided a solution which works for any size of array... Just using [**Dynamic array allocation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

> **Note** :  `lsa` stands for *'largest contiguous sub-array'*

- Here's the main function, function declarations and global variables :

*(description is given in comments)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//array pointer
int *array;
//size of lsa and its starting index value, same as i,j in your code
int lsa_size=1,lsa_start_index=0;

//function to find sum of sub array
int sum(int size_of_array, int start_index);

//the lsa function in your code
void lsaf(int *array,int size_of_array);

//main funtion
int main()
{
    int size, index;

    //scanning size of input array
    printf("enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    //creates required amount of space for array
    array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(array==NULL) //check if successfully created or not
    {
        //if not successful exit by returning 1
        printf(" memory creation unsuccessful\n enter any key to exit : ");
        exit(1);
    }

    //input of array elements
    printf("enter array elements\n");
    for(index=0 ; index < size ; index++)
        scanf("%d",&array[index]);

    //function call ... function described below
    lsaf(array,size);

    //printing largest contiguous sub-array
    printf("answer : ");
    for(index=0 ; index < lsa_size ; index++)
    {
        printf("(%d)->",array[lsa_start_index]);
        lsa_start_index++;
    }

    printf("*end*\n\n");

    //freeing allocated memory
    free(array);

    return 0;
}//main function
```

---

Now, `lsa` finding function (I've named it as `lsaf`) :

```
void lsaf(int *array,int size_of_array)
{
    int subarray_size,start_index,number_of_arrays;
    int lsa_sum=sum(1,0);//initializing sum of lsa as first element
    int subarray_sum;

    for(subarray_size = 1; subarray_size <= size_of_array ; subarray_size++)
    {
        number_of_arrays = size_of_array - subarray_size +1;
        for(start_index=0;start_index < number_of_arrays ; start_index++)
        {
            subarray_sum=sum( subarray_size,start_index);
            if(subarray_sum >= lsa_sum)
            {
                //updating lsa size and starting index
                lsa_sum=subarray_sum;
                lsa_size=subarray_size;
                lsa_start_index=start_index;
            }
        }//start_index loop
    }//subarray_size loop
}//lsaf function
```

- first loop decides the size of sub array
- second loop decides the starting index of the sub array

and now instead of the third loop, I've created the function `sum()`, this calculates the sum of elements of sub array :

```
int sum(int size_of_array, int start_index)
{
    int add=0,index;
    for(index=0; index < size_of_array ; index++)
    {
        add+=array[start_index];
        start_index++;
    }
    return add;
}//sum function
```

- so instead of making 3 loops, I've made a function for the third loop and I call it to calculate sum of sub array

I hope you understand the above functions... if any doubts feel free to ask me via comments :)

---

So putting all together your **code** would be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//array pointer
int *array;
//size of lsa and its starting index value
int lsa_size=1,lsa_start_index=0;

//function to find sum of sub array
int sum(int size_of_array, int start_index);

//the lsa function
void lsaf(int *array,int size_of_array);

//main funtion
int main()
{
    int size, index;

    //scanning size of input array
    printf("enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    //creates required amount of space for array
    array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(array==NULL) //check if successfully created or not
    {
        //if not successful exit by returning 1
        printf(" memory creation unsuccessful\n enter any key to exit : ");
        exit(1);
    }

    //input of array elements
    printf("enter array elements\n");
    for(index=0 ; index < size ; index++)
        scanf("%d",&array[index]);

    //function call
    lsaf(array,size);

    //printing largest contiguous sub-array
    printf("answer : ");
    for(index=0 ; index < lsa_size ; index++)
    {
        printf("(%d)->",array[lsa_start_index]);
        lsa_start_index++;
    }

    printf("*end*\n\n");

    //freeing allocated memory
    free(array);

    return 0;
}//main function


int sum(int size_of_array, int start_index)
{
    int add=0,index;
    for(index=0; index < size_of_array ; index++)
    {
        add+=array[start_index];
        start_index++;
    }
    return add;
}//sum function


void lsaf(int *array,int size_of_array)
{
    int subarray_size,start_index,number_of_arrays;
    int lsa_sum=sum(1,0);//initializing sum of lsa as first element
    int subarray_sum;

    for(subarray_size = 1; subarray_size <= size_of_array ; subarray_size++)
    {
        number_of_arrays = size_of_array - subarray_size +1;
        for(start_index=0;start_index < number_of_arrays ; start_index++)
        {
            subarray_sum=sum( subarray_size,start_index);
            if(subarray_sum >= lsa_sum)
            {
                //updating lsa size and starting index
                lsa_sum=subarray_sum;
                lsa_size=subarray_size;
                lsa_start_index=start_index;
            }
        }//start_index loop
    }//subarray_size loop
}//lsaf function
```

---

**Sample input and output :**

```
enter size of array
6
enter array elements
1
-3
0
2
11
-90
answer : (0)->(2)->(11)->*end*
```